# Access all declared components in a module?

Tags: angular

I have multiple components declared in a module and I want to assign a css class to all their host property. Does Angular support a way where I can just assign a class through the module or do I have to individually do this on every component?

Comment: you have to do it individually

Comment: Maybe the best way to achieve what you want would be with a common @import https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#css-imports in each component within module. There's no 'special' selector I'm aware of.